# Help identify this shower valve/cartridge

Tags: plumbing, repair, shower

I’m not sure what brand it is and it’s leaking badly. I’m pretty sure it’s older, since the house was built in 1978 and guessing it’s been awhile since the faucet was replaced. It’s a three way/one handle tub/shower setup. [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site!  An image of the handle part might help other people recognize what brand it is.

Comment: I don’t have a picture of it and can’t take one at the moment because I’m not home, but it’s basically like this one:  https://www.citymill.com/generic-moen-replacement-tub-shower-handle

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a **very** old Moen part. You may be able to match it up with a new composite cartridge, but that is doubtful. It is probably time to replace the entire valve.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is the internal section of the stem and the outside metal section of the stem may still be in the pipe.

Comment: While you may be correct, I'm not quite sure how this answers the question of identification... Please take the [tour] to see our expectations here for answers to the questions asked.